# iPhone photo app communication with Rails server

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, json, image

I am building an iPhone app which uploads/downloads photos to a Rails server. How should I transfer my photos to/from the Rails server to iPhone? Should I use JSON? My Rails app supports a RESTful architecture. Any pointers to examples would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did something similar, and would suggest using ASIHTTP on the iPhone side, communicating with your Rails app.

Here is how to use ASIHTTP: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Pay special attention to the section "Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest"

You can attach photos (or any file, really) simply by saying

```
[request setFile:@"photo.jpg" forKey:@"photo"]
```

Then you can access/manipulate it on the Rails side through your params

Comment: Thanks. How would you handle image uploads/downloads on Rails server side. I found on stack overflow that paperclip gem can be used for image uploads.

Comment: Yes paperclip is the most used gem for this purpose and would probably work fine